# X11 window scrambled when connecting

Tags: x11

I've set up XCA on a CentOS VPS box. Now, when I ssh to the server in my X11.app terminal screen with the -x flag, I manage to get onto my server. Then when I execute 'xca', the following happens:

http://postimg.org/image/lqvkr0o7f/

Any clue to un-scramble this ASCII trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by running yum install xorg-x11-fonts-*